# Attach Model to Sequelize Object

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

It has been a while since I used sequelize and I recently started a new setup with the sequelize-cli tool that appears to have a very templated approach to model generation and I'm trying to determine how I can access my model to make queries. In my attempt below, I at first thought I was accessing the model object incorrectly, but when I console log the sequelize object I noticed the `Model` property with an empty object. Is this technically where the model reference should come from? Is there something else I should be adjusting outside of initializing from the cli and generating the model in the same way?

**Logging sequelize object in my API call:**

```
import db from '../../models/index';
```

`console.log(db)`
As you can see below `models: {}` is empty and from what I believe, should be populated with the `users` model defined in `users.js`

```
{
  sequelize: Sequelize {
    options: {
        ...
    },
    config: {
      ...
    },
    dialect: PostgresDialect {
      ...
    },
    queryInterface: PostgresQueryInterface {
      sequelize: [Circular],
      queryGenerator: [PostgresQueryGenerator]
    },
    models: {},
    modelManager: ModelManager { models: [], sequelize: [Circular] },
    connectionManager: ConnectionManager {
      ...
    }
  }, ...
```

**Here is the index.js that was generated by the cli (Would love an explanation of how it is supposed to automatically recognize models):**

**`/models/index.js`**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/sequelize.js')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    console.log(db[model.name])
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**`/models/users.js`**:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  users.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    },
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'users',
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    define: {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'users'
    }
  });
  return users;
};
```

Comment: Check if you can reach `forEach` handler of `readdirSync`

Comment: It does not. It reaches `.filter` which returns a boolean response 21 times with 6 = `false` and 15 = `true`

Comment: Try to output `readdirSync(__dirname)` to console and add the result to your post

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it is syncing the root directory of my computer? `[...,'etc', 'home', 'opt', 'private', 'sbin', 'tmp', 'usr', 'var']`

Comment: `console.log(__dirname)` returns `/`

Comment: Maybe your working directory is wrong, check settings and how and from where you execute the app

Comment: Yes, I figured out the solution. It seems like the boilerplate the cli generates doesn't adapt to all environments perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `sequelize-cli` generator for `init` and `model` doesn't always adapt to an app environment as expected. There are three issues with the boilerplate that is created.

1. `fs.readdirSync(__dirname)` is syncing the parent directory on my computer, not my application directory
2. `const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);` runs into the same issue, which should be loading the js files within your model directory
3. `const Sequelize = require('sequelize');` is missing from the model generator, `users.js` which is referenced in `const model = require(...)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);`. Without it, it will throw an error that Sequelize is missing

Here is the correct code:

I used `process.cwd()` and appended `'/models/'` to correct the folder location issues.

**index.js (Updated portion of code):**

```
fs
  .readdirSync(process.cwd() + '/models/') // Updated
  .filter(file => {
    console.log(file)
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    console.log('file + Sequelize')
    console.log(Sequelize);
    const model = require('.' + path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes); // Updated
    console.log(db[model.name])
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

**users.js (Updated portion of code):**

```
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
```